# Firebase Anonymous Authentication same reference object issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, anonymous

I want to delete the Anonymous account in my Firebase Authentication database when login with the non-anonymous accounts (Google Login, Facebook login, etc).

In my code below, when user opens app Anonymous account creating successfully and I set the anonymous `FirebaseUser` object to `firebaseUserAnonymous`.

But when I log in with Google account `uidOld` and `uidNew` ids is the same every time!

So I debug my code and see `onAuthStateChanged` method's `FirebaseUser` object and before set `firebaseUserAnonymous` object is the same!

if `(firebaseUserAnonymous != null && !uidNew.equals(uidOld))` is never calling, because the new `firebaseUser` object and the old `firebaseUserAnonymous` object **always same reference**?

So `onAuthStateChanged`  method is always using the same object when new anonymous login or google login.

How can I delete the old `FirebaseUser` anonymous object when the user login with google log in?

```
private FirebaseUser firebaseUserAnonymous;

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser == null) {//When first open or logout
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
        } else {
            String uidOld = firebaseUserAnonymous != null ? firebaseUserAnonymous.getUid() : null;
            String uidNew = firebaseUser.getUid();

            if (firebaseUserAnonymous != null && !uidNew.equals(uidOld)) {//Must be call when user login after google login for delete old anonymous account, but never calling
                firebaseUserAnonymous.delete();
            }

            if (firebaseUser.isAnonymous()) {
                firebaseUserAnonymous = firebaseUser;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI: On Stack Overflow, backtick quotes are used for marking bits of code, not bold.

Comment: @DougStevenson OK thanks for fixes.